# jsPlumb connecting custom overlays - endpoint not moved

Tags: jsplumb

I am creating custom overlays for my connections in jsPlumb.

```
connectorOverlays: [
        ["Custom", {
            create: function(component) {
              return connectionNode();
            },
            location:0.5,
            id:"customOverlay"
        }]
    ]
```

connectionNode() creates a div with a select list in it. The divs themselves should be connectable, i.e., I want to connect two labels of different connectors.

```
  var overlay_div = $(connection.overlays[0].canvas);
  jsPlumb.addEndpoint(overlay_div, { anchor:[ "Perimeter", { shape:"Rectangle"}] }, relationEndpoint);
```

Enpoint on the connector overlay is defined as such:

```
var relationEndpoint = {
        endpoint:["Dot", {radius:4} ],
        anchor: ["BottomRight","TopLeft", "TopRight", "BottomLeft"],
        paintStyle:{ fillStyle:"#ff33333", opacity:0.5 },
        isSource:true,
        connectorStyle:{ strokeStyle:"#ff33333", lineWidth:3 },
        connector : "Flowchart",
        isTarget:true,
        dropOptions : {
        tolerance:"touch",
        hoverClass:"dropHover",
        activeClass:"dragActive"
    },
        beforeDetach:function(conn) { 
            return confirm("Detach connection?"); 
        }
    };
```

When I now move any of the original nodes that are connected by the connection with the custom overlay, the endpoint is not moved along with the label but remains static where it was created. Can I somehow trigger its movement programatically or am I missing some configuration option?

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to accomplish what you were doing here and having trouble with syntax. Are you able to provide insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem too. I was able to fix it with

```
instance.draggable(jsPlumb.getSelector(".flowchart-demo .window"), { grid: [5, 5] });
```

where `".flowchart-demo .window"` is the class of the div.

The example shown is from jplumb page examples... in my project this line stays

```
instance.draggable(jsPlumb.getSelector(".flowchart-demo .clsExecutando"), { grid: [5, 5] });
```

I hope this information helps you.