# JsPlumb Dynamic Endpoints as Connection Overlays

Tags: jsplumb

I am trying to create dynamic endpoints as overlays on my connections and running into issues. I am trying to model what this person has here on SO:

[jsPlumb connecting custom overlays - endpoint not moved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16860785/jsplumb-connecting-custom-overlays-endpoint-not-moved)

However, no matter what I try to do when I get to this point:

```
var overlay_div = $(connection.overlays[0].canvas);
```

I cannot get the connection to be recognized. I've tried to put this logic in the bind connection but that didn't work either when trying to establish the connection overlay. Any assistance on this would be extremely helpful.

Comment: please create a fiddle, demonstrating the issue.

Comment: Okay, here is a start to the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/janessaallen/c3b514wf/9/

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: loadFlowchartNodes is not defined ` & `connectionNode()` creates an endpoint, but there is no element to attach the endpoint to, instead it should be returning a `div` element which probally act as the custom overlay for each of the connections.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nitincool4urchat/c3b514wf/12/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/nitincool4urchat/c3b514wf/14/

First,  Create custom elements as overlays

Second,  Make sure that these elements have unique IDs

Third, Bind to the `connection` event to create endPoints on these custom-overlays.

```
jsPlumb.ready(function() {
        // setup some defaults for jsPlumb.
        instance = jsPlumb.getInstance({
            Endpoint : ["Dot", {radius:2}],
            HoverPaintStyle : {strokeStyle:"#1e8151", lineWidth:4 },
            ConnectionOverlays : [
                [ "Arrow", {
                    location:1,
                    id:"arrow",
                    length:14,
                    foldback:0.8
                }]
                ,["Custom", {
                    create: function(component) {
                        return connectionNode();
                    },
                    location:0.5
                }]
                //,[ "Label", { label:"Connect To", id:"label", cssClass:"aLabel" }]
            ],
            Container: "flowchart-demo"
        });


        var relationEndpoint = {
            endpoint: ["Dot", { radius: 2 }],
            isSource: true,
            connector: ["Flowchart", { stub: [40, 60], cornerRadius: 5, alwaysRespectStubs: true }],
            connectorStyle: { strokeStyle: "#5c96bc", lineWidth: 4, outlineColor: "transparent", outlineWidth: 4 },
            maxConnections: 5,
            onMaxConnections: function (info, e) {
                alert("Maximum connections (" + info.maxConnections + ") reached");
            },
            isTarget: true,
            dropOptions: {
                tolerance: "touch",
                hoverClass: "dropHover",
                activeClass: "dragActive"
            },
            beforeDetach: function (conn) {
                return confirm("Detach connection?");
            }
        };

        function connectionNode() {
            //var overlay_div = $(connection.ConnectionOverlays[0].canvas);
            //jsPlumb.addEndpoint({ anchor: ["Perimeter", { shape: "Rectangle" }] }, relationEndpoint);
            return $("<div>Custom</div>",{id:Date.now()}).css({border:'1px solid black',background:'green'});
        }


        var windows = jsPlumb.getSelector(".flowchart-demo .window");

        instance.draggable(windows);

        instance.bind("connection", function(info) {
            console.dir(info.connection);
            console.dir(info.connection.getOverlays());
            console.dir(info.connection.getOverlays()[1].canvas);
            var overlay_div = $(info.connection.getOverlays()[1].canvas);        
            jsPlumb.addEndpoint(overlay_div,{ anchor: ["Perimeter", { shape: "Rectangle" }] }, relationEndpoint);        
        });


        // suspend drawing and initialise.
        instance.doWhileSuspended(function() {
            var isFilterSupported = instance.isDragFilterSupported();
            // make each ".ep" div a source and give it some parameters to work with.  here we tell it
            // to use a Continuous anchor and the StateMachine connectors, and also we give it the
            // connector's paint style.  note that in this demo the strokeStyle is dynamically generated,
            // which prevents us from just setting a jsPlumb.Defaults.PaintStyle.  but that is what i
            // would recommend you do. Note also here that we use the 'filter' option to tell jsPlumb
            // which parts of the element should actually respond to a drag start.
            // here we test the capabilities of the library, to see if we
            // can provide a `filter` (our preference, support by vanilla
            // jsPlumb and the jQuery version), or if that is not supported,
            // a `parent` (YUI and MooTools). I want to make it perfectly
            // clear that `filter` is better. Use filter when you can.
            if (isFilterSupported) {
                instance.makeSource(windows, {
                    filter:".ep",
                    anchor:"Continuous",
                    connector: ["Flowchart", { stub: [40, 60], cornerRadius: 5, alwaysRespectStubs: true }],
                    connectorStyle:{ strokeStyle:"#5c96bc", lineWidth:4, outlineColor:"transparent", outlineWidth:4 },
                    maxConnections:5,
                    onMaxConnections:function(info, e) {
                        alert("Maximum connections (" + info.maxConnections + ") reached");
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                var eps = jsPlumb.getSelector(".ep");
                for (var i = 0; i < eps.length; i++) {
                    var e = eps[i], p = e.parentNode;
                    instance.makeSource(e, {
                        parent:p,
                        anchor:"Continuous",
                        connector: ["Flowchart", { stub: [40, 60], cornerRadius: 5, alwaysRespectStubs: true }],
                        connectorStyle:{ strokeStyle:"#5c96bc",lineWidth:4, outlineColor:"transparent", outlineWidth:4 },
                        maxConnections:5,
                        onMaxConnections:function(info, e) {
                            alert("Maximum connections (" + info.maxConnections + ") reached");
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });

        // initialise all '.w' elements as connection targets.
        instance.makeTarget(windows, {
            dropOptions:{ hoverClass:"dragHover" },
            anchor:"Continuous",
            allowLoopback:true,
            anchor:"Continuous"
        });

        jsPlumb.fire("jsPlumbDemoLoaded", instance);

    });
```

Comment: Isn't that what the overlay div was supposed to be for? The div to attach the endpoint to?

Comment: sorry, didn't understand.

Comment: Simon from jsPlumbToolkit just wrote me back saying that an endpoint cannot be added as an overlay. :-(

Comment: yeah, but an overlay can be added an endpoint. Also, the reverse is not possible since `overlays` don't exist unless connection is created.